# how to partition a step based on the database volume

Tags: spring-batch

below is my job configuration for paritioning a step.

```
    <!-- master step, 10 threads (grid-size)  -->
    <step id="masterStep">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </step>

</job>

<!-- Jobs to run -->
<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="jdbcWriter"
            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="1" />
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

and below is my partitioning java class

```
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();

    int range = 5;
    int fromId = 1;
    int toId = range;

    for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
        ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

        System.out.println("\nStarting : Thread" + i);
        System.out.println("fromId : " + fromId);
        System.out.println("toId : " + toId);

        value.putInt("fromId", fromId);
        value.putInt("toId", toId);

        // give each thread a name
        value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);

        result.put("partition" + i, value);

        fromId = toId + 1;
        toId += range;

    }

    return result;
```

from the above configuration I can able to work with the partitioning, 10 threads will be running and each thread will process 5 records.

there are 2 scenarios

1.if there are only 5 records the remaining 9 threads are processing no data
2.If there is a frequent change in the volume of data one day there is 5 records and one day there is 1 million records in this case I can not configure the grid size and range daily if I hard code them in the file.

so now my requirement is to dynamaically threads should be processed based on the volume of the database i.e based on the no of rows in a particular table.

please suggest me for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Batch there is a sample for partitioning database records.  That sample uses a class called the [ColumnRangePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java).  That class demonstrates how to query for the min and the max id, then partition based on that.  You can grab that class directly from Github and use it in your own code or just apply the principal.

Comment: @MichaelMinnela - Could you please guide if I have almost 10 millions records in DB what could be the gridSize and Pagination Size ?